# Arduino project:automatic room light controller

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I am Working on an Arduino mini project. its to design an automatic room light controller using IR modules  and arduino UNO R3. Before coming to my question i'd explain it a bit .Its like an arduino is connected to an IR module and a counter keeps  count of people entering  the room, when the room is empty light turns off  automatically.But my Code isnt working the way im  expecting it to work. . given below is the code for my mini project.

```
#define x 14     // x sensor 1
#define y 19     // y sensor 2
#define relay 2  // relay for output

int count = 0; // initialisation

// void IN() //{ count ++;} // void OUT() // { cout--; // }

void setup()
{ 
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(x, INPUT);
    pinMode(y, INPUT);
    pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{ 
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:            
    if(digitalRead(x))      //IN();
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (digitalRead(y))    // OUT();
    {
        count--;
    }
    if (count <= 0) {
        digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
        delay(20);
    }
    else
        digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
}
```

The problem with my code is that the transmitter and receiver sense interference both at the same time resulting in  turning of the light while the person is still inside the room.As im new to arduino need your inputs.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic of the *layout* of your *sensors* in the *environment*? It's hard to tell what is going wrong by just staring at the code. The first **fix** you should try is adding a **debounce** to your *sensor reads*, since *false reads* can happen even in the perfect environmental conditions and setup.

Comment: http://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/automatic-room-light-controller-with-bidirectional-visitor-counter-using-arduino    @PatrickTrentin  Following is the link to the project details. though ive changed it a bit. As i not really needed an LCD but rest goes the same.

Comment: You forgot to put `delay(1000);` after `count++;` and `count--;`, which *-in the original project-* is intended to *prevent* the exact issue you are experiencing. Anyway, *IMHO* it's a **very brittle** approach and prone to failures.